# One function to rule them all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coding an application which displays balls obeying certain laws of physics.
So I have a Ball Object, and a path prototype. This path prototype calculates the coordinates of the ball at any given moment and draws it, that goes kinda like this :

```js
Ball.prototype.path = function(v) {
modifying the ball coordinates...
ctx.arc(....);
(other canvas stuff)}
```

If I want to display an animation of the ball, I do this:

```js
var ball1 = new Ball(...);
var ball2...
function loop () {
ctx.beginPath(); // The balls won't show up if I begin and close the Path in path(), I don't know why...
ball1.path();
ball2...
ctx.closePath();
};
setInterval(loop, 0.0015);
```

But I want to add a button which adds and displays balls. So I'm looking for a function which executes these commands to any ball added.

It's a little bit tricky, because it has to:

1. Create and name a new variable.
2. Execute path() according to that name.
3. All of that, in the same loop function so I can make a setInterval later.

**EDIT: FIXED**
@Frederik @Doorknob I've used a BallArray:

`var BallArray = new Array(); i=0; function AddBallonClick() { i++; BalleArray.push(i) }; function loop() { for (var i=0;i<BalleArray.length;i++) { ctx.beginPath(); var ball = new Ball(0, 0, 40); ball.path(); ctx.closePath(); }; }; setInterval(loop, dt);`

But I want to name the new variables ball_i, ie: ball_1, ball_2..., and I don't know how to. The script doesn't seem to be working even when I add the ball just once, so that's a problem too...

**EDIT 2: FIXED**

Also, I want to set an initial speed to every new ball, typically I do this:

```
   ball.v = new V(...);
```

But now that I have an array, I added this to the loop, but it doesn't work...:

```
   balles[i].v = new V(...)
```

**EDIT 3:**

I have another problem, whenever I click the button, a ball is not added and drawn, but instead the animation "replays". It seems that javascript can't draw balls at the same time with my kind of code:

```
    function loop()
    {
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        balls[i].path();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
};
    setInterval(loop, dt);
```

EDIT: ALL FIXED
I've solved the last problem you just have to put the `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)` in the loop function but before the `for(var i=0...)`.

Thanks to all of you :) !

Comment: Do you know what an array is? If you do, then use an array and loop through it. If not, Google search it and learn how to use them. Also nice LOTR referencing title :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and for the title compliment!
I am reading now more about arrays, but I can't find out how to apply the array name to the path function. Right, I'm doing this:
`i=1;
function loop()
{
for (var i in Ball) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 array[i].path();
 ctx.closePath();
 i++;
};
}
setInterval(loop, dt);`

Comment: You can either use an array directly or define a `BallArray` object, just like `Ball`, except that it would contain some `Ball` objects (an array! :) ) into it and do stuff for everything that's in it. The second approach can be helpful to control distinct groups of Balls.

Comment: @Frederik @Doorknob I've done this: `var BallArray = new Array();
i=0;
function AddBallonClick() {
i++;
BalleArray.push(i)
};
function loop()
{
for (var i=0;i<BalleArray.length;i++) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 var ball = new Ball(0, 0, 40);
 ball.path();
 ctx.closePath();
};
};
setInterval(loop, dt);`
But I want to name the new variables ball_i, ie: ball_1, ball_2..., and I don't know how to. The script doesn't seem to be working even when I add the ball just once, so that's a problem too...

Comment: I got lazy near the end. maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/RgGyL/) will help

Comment: @rlemon Thanks a lot man ! Your implementation seems very interesting, but can your answer be more specific. Now that I've done the arrays, I need to specify an initial speed for every created ball. Typically it works like this : ball.v = new V(...);
But now that I have an array, I don't know what to use...

Comment: @user2352011: First create the ball and then add it to the array, e.g., `var ball = new Ball(...); ball.v = new V(...); balls.push(ball);`

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks a lot man !
Now I just have a canvas conflict I think. When I click on the button, new balls are created, their coordinates are calculated and everything, but they won't show up at the same time. Any tip ?

Comment: @user2352011: There's a lot of different things that could cause that. I'd recommend you check that you've got `var` in all the right places so unintentionally-global variables aren't interacting with each other and make sure that you only do `clearRect` once per frame, rather than once per ball.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the answer is arrays. You don't seem to quite understand them, so here's a quick overview. An array is sort of a list of objects. In your case, you probably want a list of `Ball`s. You can initialize it like this:

```
var balls = [];  // [] is about the same as new Array(), but more concise
```

To add a new ball to it, you can use `push`, passing it the ball:

```
balls.push(new Ball(/* ... */));
```

(You could, of course, pass it an already-existing ball, too:)

```
var ball = /* obtain ball from elsewhere */;
balls.push(ball);
```

You do seem to understand how to loop through the arrays, but not how to get the values as you loop through it. To loop through the array, you use a `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Obviously, `i` will be an integer from `0` to `balls.length`. We can't do much with the number on its own, though; what we really want is the ball at that index in the array. You can do this by *indexing* the array. That would look like this:

```
var ball = balls[i];
```

Now `ball` contains the ball at position `i` in the `balls` array, and you can do whatever you want with it from there. In your case, you probably want to call `path` on it:

```
// If you've stored it into a variable as above:
ball.path();
// Or more concisely without having to store it into a variable:
balls[i].path();
```

With arrays, there is no need for variables named, e.g., `ball_1`, `ball_2`, etc. Instead, you just have an array, `balls`, and index it, e.g., `balls[0]`, `balls[1]`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You were right, I hadn't well grasped the concept of arrays before.

Comment: As for the code, I have two problems:
Whenever I click the button, a ball is not added, but instead the animation "replays".
Also, I want to set an initial speed to every new ball, but when I add this to the loop, it doesn't work...:
balles[i].v = new V(900, 0);

Comment: @user2352011 is v not a property of ball? you should go for something like `balls.push(new Ball("ball_"+i, v))` while `i` is the number of your ball and `v`the initial velocity